# MYSQL: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails SHELL

Tags: mysql, shell

it gives me an error **Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails** , I want to drop table, using this code

```
ignore_table=`mysql -u$dbUser -p$dbPass -e "SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000; SELECT CONCAT( 'DROP TABLE ', GROUP_CONCAT(table_name) , ';' ) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = '$dbName' AND table_name NOT IN ($IGNORED_TABLES_STRING_EXEC);" -s`

         echo $ignore_table

         mysql -u$dbUser -p$dbPass $dbName -e "$ignore_table"
```

Comment: don't be trying this at home folks, unless you know what you are doing !

Comment: @Drew ty, I already solve it

Comment: I mean those that tinker with this, as it autogenerates the drops (as you know)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

That error is pretty much self explanatory in saying that you can't drop the table cause there is some other table which is referencing one/more column in this table and so dropping this table make the reference void or orphan.

I suggest you drop the table individually by checking whether there is any foreign key reference present to that table and if present then drop that FK constraint first and then drop the table(s) rather than dropping list of tables from `information_schema.tables`.

Comment: or just do the children drops first